# which prediction algorithm can be used for multivalued attributes(columns) in R?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, predictive-models, prediction

for example 
[image: example data set]

let we have to predict the combo_name  using the meal_id but meal_id is a multivalued attribute. so in this case which prediction algorithms is to be used??

Comment: It appears that `meal_id` is intended to represent subsets of a predefined finite collection. Have you considered representing it in terms of binary indicators? That would eliminate the apparent problem and make all prediction algorithms applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the combo_name is probably a combination of meal_id's and thus behaves like a set of if-then-else rules, you could try decision trees. These built up nicely for this kind of rules.

In R you can have a look at rpart or tree or partykit packages. I would start with rpart package (and rpart.plot package for the visualization).